# Trying to write a code to keep asking the user the same dialog until they get it correct

Tags: java

I have a code here and I'm not sure how to keep asking a question until the user answers the correct answer

```
while ((stringSize >= 0) && (stringSize <= 4) && (stringSize >= 8)){
  if ((stringSize >= 0) && (stringSize <= 4) && (stringSize >= 8)){
     System.out.println("no");
     input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word");
  }
  if (secondChar == '+' && ((stringSize >= 4) && (stringSize <= 8)))
  {
     break;
  }
}
if (secondChar == '+' && ((stringSize >= 4) && (stringSize <= 10))){
}
  System.out.println("yes");
```

Comment: have you used loops yet?

Comment: `(stringSize >= 0) && (stringSize <= 4) && (stringSize >= 8)` is **never** `true`. Nothing is both <= 4 and >= 8

Comment: What is the question really? Why do you have empty if at the end? All in all, what exactly is the purpose of this piece of code?

Comment: Never mind I figured it out. I shouldn't of post this...

Answer (score 3):

Seems like the rare case when you actually need `do ... while`.

Your conditions are never true - `stringSize` can't be less than 4 *and* greater than 8.